# Не могу клонировать репозиторий Git + Windows server 2008 + cygwin

Tags: git, windows-server-2008-r2, cygwin, tortoise-git

Есть задача ввести в эксплуатацию систему контроля версий (GIT)

Сервер для GIT - Windows Server Standart x64 2008 R2

Клиент - Windows 7 x64

На сервере установлено:

- Git-2.5.1-32-bit
- Cygwin(openSSH сервер)

На клиенте установлено:

- Git-2.5.1-32-bit
- TortoiseGit-1.8.15.0-64bit

Последовательность установки>>

Сервер:

1. Установка Cygwin
2. Установка openSSH сервера через Cygwin
3. Настройка openSSH сервера на дефолтных настройках (Подключение только по паролю пользователь git)
4. Установка Git-2.5.1-32-bit
5. Добавлено в переменные среды на сервере:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd; C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\mingw32\bin"`

6. Создание репозитория с помощью GitGUI по пути C:\repo (вот что получилось C:\repo.git)
7. Установка прав на чтение и запись (вообщем на все и для всех) на папку C:\repo

Клиент:

1. Установка Git-2.5.1-32-bit
2. установка TortoiseGit-1.8.15.0-64bit

Результат:

1. Клиент подключается к серверу по SSH (Putty) по логину git и паролю - удачно (значит SSH сервер работает)
2. По пути `C:\` ПКМ в контекстном меню выбираю Git clone...
3. В открывшемся окне URL: `ssh://git@сервер:/C:/repo`
4. Вводим пароль для пользователя git
5. Ошибка:

> `git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://git@сервер:/C:/repo" "C:\repo"`
>
> Cloning into 'C:\repo'...
>   fatal: '/C:/repo' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (8237 ms @ 14.09.2015 14:42:28)

---

### **Резюмирую**

Есть задача ввести в эксплуатацию систему контроля версий (GIT)

Сервер для GIT - Windows Server Standart x64 2008 R2

Клиент - Windows 7 x64

На сервере установлено:

-Git-2.5.1-32-bit

-Cygwin(openSSH сервер)

На клиенте установлено:

-Git-2.5.1-32-bit

-TortoiseGit-1.8.15.0-64bit

Последовательность установки>>

Сервер:

1. Установка Cygwin
2. Установка openSSH сервера через Cygwin
3. Настройка openSSH сервера на дефолтных настройках (Подключение только по паролю пользователь git)
4. Установка Git-2.5.1-32-bit
5. Добавлено в переменные среды на сервере

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Git\mingw32\bin"

6. Создание папки  `C:\gitrepo`
7. Установка прав на чтение и запись (вообщем на все и для всех) на папку `C:\gitrepo`
8. В gitBASH переходим в `C:\gitrepo`

   $ cd C:\gitrepo
9. Создал репозиторий

   $ git init --bare

Клиент:

1. Установка Git-2.5.1-32-bit
2. установка TortoiseGit-1.8.15.0-64bit
3. `git config --global user.name` и `git config --global user.email` выполнено

Результат:

1. Клиент подключается к серверу по `SSH` (Putty) по логину `git` и паролю - удачно (значит SSH сервер работает)
2. По пути `C:\` ПКМ в контекстном меню выбираю `Git clone...`
3. В открывшемся окне `URL: ssh://git@сервер:/cygdrive/c/gitrepo`
4. Вводим пароль для пользователя `git`
5. Ошибка:

> git.exe clone --progress -v "ssh://git@сервер:/cygdrive/c/gitrepo"
>   "C:\gitrepo"
>
> Cloning into 'C:\gitrepo'... fatal: '/cygdrive/c/gitrepo' does not
>   appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (136079 ms @ 15.09.2015
>   10:39:34)

6. в gitBASH команда `git clone ssh://git@сервер:/cygdrive/c/gitrepo`

> fatal: '/cygdrive/c/gitrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Возможно я прописываю не правильный путь клонирования?
Подскажите пожалуйста возможные варианты решения проблемы, или подскажите в чем я не прав. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Подправил вам форматирование списков, цитат и кода для лучшей читаемости.

Comment: Не нужно дополнять вопрос в ответах. Используйте кнопку [edit] под вопросом.

Comment: хорошо. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите ваш файл `/c/Users/admin/.ssh/known_hosts` - и пропишите там правильный ключ вашего сервера. Или удалите его - тогда при первом обращении ssh-клиент предложит его добавить.

Такая ошибка возникает в том случае, когда вы переустанавливаете ssh сервер (клиент видит подмену сервера и отказывается с ним соединяться). Если вы не переустанавливали сервер - возможно, вас атакует хакер. Тогда надо посмотреть на сервере в папке `(корень cygwin)/etc/ssh` правильные ключи сервера и сравнить их с теми, которые вам говорит ssh-клиент.

PS я еще понимаю, почему сообщение об ошибке не смог прочитать автор вопроса... Но почему его с первого раза не смог прочитать никто из отвечающих, включая меня?! Там же все понятно расписано :)

Comment: Хм, а это сообщение появилось буквально недавно, его не было, когда я отвечал.

Comment: "никто из отвечающих" — как будто тут много ещё отвечающих? )

Comment: На клиенте удалил файл known_hosts. Повторил команду в GitBASH на клиенте: git clone --bare  ssh://git@сервер:/cygdrive/c/gitrepo.git. Подтвердил новый ключ, ввел пароль, и вот ошибка: fatal: '/cygdrive/c/gitrepo' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @MARKSIST: уже можно говорить "та же самая ошибка" )

Comment: Просто столько ошибок) Хочу что бы была ясность.